# Start Activity of Main project from my library project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-library

I have 2 projects. One is my Main Project(A) , and another is a Library Project(B). I want to start an activity which is present in A from an activity which is located in B. How do I do that ?

I Tried `startActivity(getApplicationContext(),B.class);`
,but

**B.class**

is not resolved.

How Can I let my library project start an activity of my main project ?

Comment: Have you added your Activity B in the manifest of your Project A?

Comment: Have u Added Lib Project in Main Project

Comment: There are ways to do what you want, however that approach is not the right one. It's a cyclic reference basically, which is something you want to avoid.
Declare some listener interface in the library and set a listener from the main project instead.

Comment: i have added lib project in main

Comment: Just read these articles [Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) and [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: no, this is not something I was looking for. You are telling me that there is no way an activity can be started without an intent filter?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application

Comment: What's wrong with intent filter? For me it's a most elegent way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom Action in intent-filter of you activity and start that activity by specifying action

```
<activity android:name="my.package.MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my.package.action.MY_ACTION"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="my.package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

start activity with this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("my.package.action.MY_ACTION");
intent.addCategory(getActivity().getPackageName());
startActivity(getActivity(), intent);
```

Comment: isnt there any other way , other than adding an intent filter ?

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need to use an intent filter. The code in Activity A can use

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, "my.package.MyActivity.B");
Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(cn);

startActivity(this, intent);
```

to specify the activity B should be started.